# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid in createMaterialTopTabNavigator()/MaterialTopTabView render method, React Native w/ React Navigation v5

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am seeing the following error when using createMaterialTopTabNavigator() in React Native with React Navigation v5:

`` Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `MaterialTopTabView`. ``

The relevant code is as follows. I tried to delete anything extraneous and add ellipses as a placeholder, so apologies if I missed anything important.

**Connect.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ... } from 'react-native';
import globalStyles from '../Styles/global-styles.js';
import Sessions from './Sessions.js';
import ChatList from './ChatList.js';
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const TopTabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
function GetTopTabNavigator() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <TopTabNav.Navigator tabBarOptions={{...}}>
                <TopTabNav.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatList}/>
                <TopTabNav.Screen name="Sessions" component={Sessions}/>
            </TopTabNav.Navigator>
        <NavigationContainer/>
    );
};

class ConnectScreen extends Component {
    static router = TopTabNav.router;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...
        };
    }

    ...

    render() {
        ...

        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{...}}>
                ...
                <View style={globalStyles.container}>
                    GetTopTabNavigator()
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

export default ConnectScreen;
```

Research (and the error code) indicates that this is likely an issue with the way that a component is being imported or exported. To this end, I've tried several things:

**1.** Putting the Top Tab Navigator in a separate file, then exporting it (both as default and not with the appropriate brackets {} in the import statement) — any combinations results in either this error or another, for which the solution is to switch back to this way.

**2.** Copying the exact code from the documentation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/), pasting it in **ConnectTopTabNav.js**, then importing it using

```
import ConnectTopTabNav from './ConnectTopTabNav';
```

ConnectTopTabNav, too, I tried exporting as default and not as default, with the above corresponding to the former (shown below). Here is the code for **ConnectTopTabNav.js**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
export default function TobTabNav() {
    return ( 
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

However, the same problem results in Connect.js regardless of whether I attempt to render the component as ConnectTopTabNav() or . I also tried putting the above code directly into Connect.js, to no avail.

**3.** Looking through the @react-navigation/material-top-tabs file structure for any import/export errors. Didn't find anything, which isn't too surprising.

**4.** Putting the navigator inside my App.js navigation structure in several fashions. Also a dead end.

**5.** Surrounding the navigator with the < NavigationContainer /> component, with the corresponding flag to indicate that it's independent of the main navigator. (*Edit*: I've added this to the code to reflect this change.)

The error has arisen since upgrading to @react-navigation version 5. In version 4, I was able to create the navigator within the createMaterialTopTabNavigator() method directly, and didn't see an error.

I am using version 5.4.2 of @react-navigation/native and version 5.2.16 @react-navigation/material-top-tabs, on React Native v0.61.5. Appreciate any insight anyone can provide — I just don't see where else there's room for an error here. Please let me know if you need any other information. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: the solution was ultimately to update the version of react-native-tab-view, which @react-navigation/material-top-tabs is dependent upon. With the latest react-native-tab-view version, 2.15.1, and version 5.2.16 of @react-navigation/material-top-tabs, my navigator is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you should normally wrap your navigation components at the top level with the Navigation container and I don't see it on your code sample. You should have something like this:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
// Your other imports

<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I'd tried that, as referenced in number 5 (though I'm not sure it displayed the text correctly in my question — edited to make sure it was there), but it didn't have any impact on the error. I've updated my code and my question to include that component though. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I didn't go through point 5 my bad. Your code seems fine, I ran it on my side and didn't have any problems. Maybe try reinstalling all the packages in your folder?

Comment: No worries. I have tried reinstalling both node_modules and pods, to no effect. The one thing I haven't tried is running this code in an entirely separate app, so I'll give that a shot and see if it goes anywhere.

Comment: As you can see, the solution was ultimately to update one of the dependent packages. I hadn't even realize it was related until you made me think to look more into that. So, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!